# Convert VB.Net "If' statement to use "Select" instead

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

```
If s > 0 Then
    sh = (4 * s * 3.14)

    Console.WriteLine("Sqhere Area")
    Console.WriteLine(sh)
Else
```

How to convert it to `select case` instead of `If/Else`?

Comment: Why would you? It’s a single condition.

Comment: What programming language are you asking for? You have java, javascript, .net (which could be multiple languages) and vb.net tagged.

Comment: @RyanWilson  visual studio

Comment: Hi, just a small tip .. Visual Studio is just the development environment for several programming languages such as vb.net, c# f# and quite a lot of others :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.Net it would be like this:

```
SELECT CASE s
   CASE Is > 0
       sh = (4 * s * 3.14)
   CASE ELSE
       'Something
END SELECT
```